# ipad external video mirroring detection with UIScreen

Tags: xcode, ipad, video

I am using [UIScreen screens] for detecting the external screens but will this also work for Airplay mirroring? Also, with [UIScreen screens], how can I check if the output is analog (vga, composite, component) or digital (hdmi)?

Comment: Why do you need to know the output type? I am not sure this information is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, an Airplay screen counts as another screen.